# How to Custom Hyperlink in Power BI matrix - NOT https:

Tags: sql-server, hyperlink, powerbi

my Power BI report is working a treat.  The customer has now asked for a click through in the matrix which takes them to an inhouse application with parameters.  I have coded the URl inside the stored proc, so that the URL is generated at the time the table is populated so is all ready to og.

I have added a Web URL column to my datatyping in the back of PowerBi but the address is not being recognised - I guess it is because it doesn't start https: or www.... I have tested the theory an can hyperlink to Google (other search engines are available), but as soon as it is my internal protocol it draws a blank.

Does anyone have any ideas please?

I am generating something like internalprotocol://corp7500,297,23  where we have screen number, and then 2 parameters passed through.

The problem is more with PowerBI recognising the text as a hyperlink than the hyperlink itself.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Oct 2017, Power BI only supports the following link types for URL:

- http
- https
- mailto
- news
- telnet
- ftp
- file

You can see more information [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-may-feature-summary/#urlTables), and submit new request for other link supports in the [forum](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas).